# Can someone help explain this scheme procedure

Tags: lisp, scheme

Question:

```
((lambda (x y) (x y)) (lambda (x) (* x x)) (* 3 3))
```

This was #1 on the midterm, I put "81 9" he thought I forgot to cross one out lawl, so I cross out 81, and he goes aww. Anyways, I dont understand why it's 81.

I understand why `(lambda (x) (* x x)) (* 3 3) = 81`, but the first lambda I dont understand what the x and y values are there, and what the `[body] (x y)` does.

So I was hoping someone could explain to me why the first part doesn't seem like it does anything.

Comment: why would you add the tag homework ddaa? it isnt homework it was a test question i got wrong, and i was looking for information on why.

Comment: Mh... Because I could! Right, that was not warranted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This needs some indentation to clarify

```
((lambda (x y) (x y))
 (lambda (x) (* x x))
 (* 3 3))
```

- `(lambda (x y) (x y))`; call `x` with `y` as only parameter.
- `(lambda (x) (* x x))`; evaluate to the square of its parameter.
- `(* 3 3)`; evaluate to 9

So the whole thing means: "call the square function with the 9 as parameter".

EDIT: The same thing could be written as

```
((lambda (x) (* x x))
 (* 3 3))
```

I guess the intent of the exercise is to highlight how evaluating a scheme form involves an implicit function application.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at this again...

```
((lambda (x y) (x y)) (lambda (x) (* x x)) (* 3 3))
```

To evaluate a form we evaluate each part of it in turn. We have three elements in our form. This one is on the first (function) position:

```
(lambda (x y) (x y))
```

This is a second element of a form and a first argument to the function:

```
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

Last element of the form, so a second argument to the function.

```
(* 3 3)
```

Order of evaluation doesn't matter in this case, so let's just start from the left.

```
(lambda (x y) (x y))
```

Lambda creates a function, so this evaluates to a function that takes two arguments, x and y, and then applies x to y (in other words, calls x with a single argument y). Let's call this **call-1**.

```
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

This evaluates to a function that takes a single argument and returns a square of this argument. So we can just call this **square**.

```
(* 3 3)
```

This obviously evaluates to **9**.

OK, so after this first run of evaluation we have:

```
(call-1 square 9)
```

To evaluate this, we call **call-1** with two arguments, **square** and **9**. Applying **call-1** gives us:

```
(square 9)
```

Since that's what **call-1** does - it calls its first argument with its second argument. Now, square of **9** is **81**, which is the value of the whole expression.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps translating that code to Common Lisp helps clarify its behaviour:

```
((lambda (x y) (funcall x y)) (lambda (x) (* x x)) (* 3 3))
```

Or even more explicitly:

```
(funcall (lambda (x y) (funcall x y))
         (lambda (x) (* x x))
         (* 3 3))
```

Indeed, that first lambda doesn't do anything useful, since it boils down to:

```
(funcall (lambda (x) (* x x)) (* 3 3))
```

which equals

```
(let ((x (* 3 3)))
  (* x x))
```

equals

```
(let ((x 9))
  (* x x))
```

equals

```
(* 9 9)
```

equals 81.

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted so far are good, so rather than duplicating what they already said, perhaps here is another way you could look at the program:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (call-with arg fun) (fun arg))

(call-with (* 3 3) square)
```

Does it still look strange?